# how to get video from analog camera recorder (HIWATCH DS-T101) from Python OpenCV

Tags: opencv

How to get video from analog camera recorder (HIWATCH DS-T101) from Python OpenCV. I found information on getting video from the IP camera. How do I do the same for an analog camera?

```
#receiving video from IP camera
import cv2######################ip camers
stream = cv2.VideoCapture('access protocol://login_cam:password_cam@IP')

while True:

    r, f = stream.read()
    cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream',f)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: how is the camera connected to the computer? As you have mentioned the camera is analog do you have a analog to digital converter for the video stream?

Comment: Initially, I wrote a little incorrectly. The video goes from the cameras to the recorder and from it I need to get the video

Comment: Can you elaborate the questions with these details(i.e. make and model for the recorder and its available interfaces)?

Comment: I use recorder "hiwatch ds-104g"

Comment: are you able to open the `RTSP` stream from the recorder using `VLC media player` or something similar. Refer the documentation manual on connecting to the RTSP stream. You can follow the same approach which you have mentioned in your questions.

Comment: I contacted the equipment supplier. He explained that access to the video stream can be obtained here:(rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.200.11:554/ISAPI/Streaming/Channels/101) but it doesn't work in Python stream = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.200.11:554/ISAPI/Streaming/Channels/101')

Comment: Can you try if the streaming works with `VLC media player`?

Comment: No in VLC media player don't work. But in native program "iVMS-4200 Client" i see camera. IP from camera pings.

Comment: Instead of the native player which has already been configured to open streams from the vendor devices, can you try and open the `RTSP` stream using a media player which supports opening streams from network. [Here](https://www.unifore.net/ip-video-surveillance/how-to-play-rtsp-video-stream-of-ip-cameras-on-vlc-player-quicktime-player.html) is a tutorial on using VLC for opening the IP camera stream.

Comment: Thanks, using VLC I realized that I had closed the port on which I was trying to access. Your advice helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Post your steps that you took to fix the issue and mark the answer as accepted so that this question is marked as closed.